# Qt error : The program has unexpectedly finished. The process was ended forcefully

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I Started new project with **Qt5**, and tried Qt Quick Project(**QML**) on Windows10(64bit).
Because I want to use various animations & effects. But I hit a brick wall, that I can't run & debug QML projects. First, I want to use swiping so I try swipe example, but the project makes an error.

The run error is first image, and the debug error is second image.

[image]

[image]

**p.s** - I tried somthing to solve the errors, which are updating NVIDIA driver, trying to release mode and making a new Qt Quick Application Project - Swipe. But everything is useless. Help me Please.

Comment: The solution to Qt crashes is always the same: download Qt sources, build Qt in debug mode, build your project (or the example project) with the Qt you just had built, and run it under the debugger. The debugger will indicate exactly where inside Qt did the code crash, and allow us to figure out how to fix or work around the issue. Before you do that’d this question is unanswerable pretty much.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much Kuba Ober! I will try that first.

Comment: @SungMo what happened?