# DLL Made with CMake makes the program crash

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, shared-libraries, libraries

I'm struggling to use a DLL generated using CMAKE and C++. I'm able to build the library, include it and build the target project, the problem is that when I run the target build it crashes immediately. 
My code is super easy and I don't know what I'm missing.
The DLL is built using CMAKE in a separate project. Here's the code

DLL PROJECT:

**CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(LibProj LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_definitions("-DBUILD_LIB")
file(GLOB
    INCLUDE_FILES
    baselibraryclass.h
    )

file(GLOB
    SOURCE_FILES
    baselibraryclass.cpp
    )

add_library(yourlib SHARED ${INCLUDE_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES} )
```

**baselibraryclass.h**

```
#ifndef BASELIBRARYCLASS_H
#define BASELIBRARYCLASS_H

#ifdef BUILD_LIB
    #define EXT_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define  EXT_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <string>

class EXT_DLL BaseLibraryClass
{
public:

     BaseLibraryClass();
};

#endif // BASELIBRARYCLASS_H
```

**baselibraryclass.cpp**

```
#include "baselibraryclass.h"

#include <iostream>

EXT_DLL BaseLibraryClass::BaseLibraryClass()
{
    std::cout << "Hi from the library Class Object " << std::endl;
}
```

Target project

**CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TargetProject LANGUAGES CXX)
#Including the path of the library header
include_directories(D:/TestingDLLNativeCpp/Library/include)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(TargetProject main.cpp)
#The path of the built library is D:/TestingDLLNativeCpp/Library/Debug/yourlib.lib
target_link_libraries(TargetProject PRIVATE D:/TestingDLLNativeCpp/Library/Debug/yourlib.lib)
```

Target project **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <baselibraryclass.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BaseLibraryClass testObk;
    return 0;
}
```

As I wrote above, cmake configures properly and the compiler is able to build for both projects, however the target executables crashes immediately.
What am I doing wrong o.O??

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Start by including the complete error from the crash

Comment: ```Starting D:\TestingDLLNativeCpp\Target\Build\TargetProject.exe ...
 The program has unexpectedly finished.
 The process was ended forcefully.
D:\TestingDLLNativeCpp\Target\Build\TargetProject.exe crashed. ```

:/

Comment: I would expect the error to be a little bit more programmer-related, not a general "The program has crashed" error.  When you debug your code, what error is detected by the debugger?

Comment: Looks like a Qt error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587138/qt-error-the-program-has-unexpectedly-finished-the-process-was-ended-forceful

Comment: Is the DLL's location/directory on your `PATH`? You have an absolute path to the link library, but you probably need to add the DLL's directory to your `PATH`. The DLL is similar to an executable: Windows has a whole set of rules on how to find a DLL and it does involve `PATH` (or `$env:PATH` if Powershell.)

Comment: since when the extension .lib is for dynamic library ? i.e. in your "Target project" `D:/TestingDLLNativeCpp/Library/Debug/yourlib.lib` seems odd to me...

Comment: You should use the library target to link to your main application: `target_link_libraries(TargetProject PRIVATE yourlib)` instead of an absolute path to your library. Also, I would highly suggest using the `GenerateExportHeader` cmake module to create the export header for DLL generation.

Comment: I solved it after a while..... actually the program crashed because the dll wasn't compiled in the same directory .... lol. Thanks for the amazing support guys ! . I solved everything by setting CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY so at every building everything is properly set.

Comment: you might want to add your solution as an *answer* and accept, so the question doesn't show up on the "awaiting your interaction" tab no more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of the dll not being included in the build directory might be solved by setting the CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY. However, a better practice would be to set the output directory of the .dll on a target basis. This will ensure that you have no unwanted side-effects in the long run.

```
set_target_property(yourlib PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```